# 1 Hz ring oscillator not working

Tags: oscillator, frequency, wave, square

Inspired by this [project](https://friedhardware.com/2016/02/28/building-a-ring-oscillator/) I built a ring oscillator that outputs a 1 Hz signal.

[image]

Using their formula, I decided to use 1K for R1 and R2, and 558 uF for C1. I used a [CD4069UB](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4069ub.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1645047035254&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fcd4069ub) CMOS inverter that has a supply voltage of 3-18 V. I used a 12 V input, 560 uF cap, and 1 K resistors.

The issue I have is instead of getting a ~12 V, 1 Hz output signal I'm getting a ~100 mV, 100 Hz output signal. I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Could it be just the chip?

Edit 1: physical construction

[image]

[image]

Comment: What kind of capacitor is used?

Comment: Have you measured the actual capacitance of the capacitor, as well as its leakage current?

Comment: The 4069's output drive strength is terrible. It's most likely just not able to drive your 1k resistors properly because it can't put out enough current. Increase the resistance of R1 and R2 to 100k and use a 5.6µF cap instead, then tell us if that changed anything.

Comment: With 2 x 100k and 5uF, simulation gives ~ 1Hz. Tested with 74AC04. Don't forget the 1uF decoupling capacitor between power supply pins.

Comment: Same with CD4069UB

Comment: I used a 80K resistor and a 22 uF cap and im getting an output of -600-600mV at 60 Hz. @Antonio51 whats the amplitude of your output?

Comment: Could you show us a picture of the circuit's physical construction?

Comment: @JonathanS. Done

Comment: You absolutely need bypass capacitors on your supply rail with this circuit. Please add at least a 100nF ceramic cap right across the chip. Additionally, you can't use a polarized capacitor in this circuit. Make the resistors larger and use a ceramic or film cap instead.

Comment: @JonathanS. I've added a 4.7 uF decoupling cap. Switched out the polarized capacitor with a 4.7 uF cap. I'm using 100 K resistors. Based on the equation I should be getting ~1 but nothing. I just checked and I'm getting the same output at all 6 inverters.

Comment: Your oscilloscope probe at the bottom without a connection to ground  will not work anyway. If the osc input is switched to AC it will not work with a signal of 1 Hz AC.

Comment: @Uwe That helped but now I’m getting a 5v dc output signal

Comment: Check all three inverter outputs with the osc probe. If you got a two channel osc check input and output of each inverter.

Comment: @Uwe Inverter 1: 0 input, 5v output. No reference crossing so no frequency. Inverter 2: input 5, output 0, no freq. Inverter 3: input 0, output 5, no frequency

Comment: Check the connection from inverter 3 output to inverter 1 input. If inverter 3 output is 5 V, inverter 1 input should not be 0.

Comment: @Uwe Based on the circuit I’m using (https://friedhardware.com/2016/02/28/building-a-ring-oscillator/) There is no connection between inverter 1 and 3.

Comment: There is a  connection from inverter 3 output to inverter 1 input by R1 and R2 in series.

Comment: @Uwe I had that node grounded. It’s working now. 990.5 mHz Thanks man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simulation with CD4069UB.
~Same as with 74AC04. Did not verify if the formula is ok.
Note that these are simulations.
Made with microcap12 http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm
Perfect capacitor. Take account of leakage current which lower frequency!
Will add an example.

[image]

[image]

And here when R3 is changed (leakage current).

[image]

Comment: What software are you using to simulate?

Comment: microcap 12   free    http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm

Answer (score 4):

1 Hz is too slow for an analog oscillator, you need too large capacitors. Electrolytic capacitors have large tolerances and high leakage currents, they should not be used for timing.

To build a reliable, stable and precise low frequency oscillator it is much better to start with a frequency between 1 kHz and 1 MHz followed by a digital frequency divider.

This method works for any very low frequency, no problem to generate a µHz or a nHz oscillator. You have to wait over 31 years for the end of the first period of a 1 nHz frequency.

A successful simulation of an analog 1 Hz oscillator is no proof that it will work as a real circuit.

Comment: Everything about your first paragraph is incorrect.  A 1 Hz (or even 0.5 Hz) oscillator is very simple and stable with a 1% tolerance resistor and a 1% tolerance film cap.  Higher precision resistors are easily available and not expensive, but CMOS transition levels wander around with temperature, negating the benefits of a better resistor.

Comment: If you don't need crystal accuracy, a simple option is the CD4060 (MC14060, etc.).  This is an oscillator plus 14-stage divider in one chip.  The capacitor size would be 1/16,000 the size of a direct 1 Hz oscillator; much easier to get, better accuracy, lower cost and size.

Answer (score 3):

You do not show your own schematic with the pin numbers of the gates, so this is all guesswork.

The network impedance is too low for the output stage of a U series CMOS gate to drive.  U stands for Un-buffered, the weakest form of CMOS.  I recommend you increase the resistors by 20x and decrease the capacitor by 20x.

Next, R2.  R2's only job is to limit the current from C1 into the left-most gate's input stage.  This is because when the output changes state, C1 forces an over-voltage onto the left gate's input.  R2 limits the current for this transient event to a safe value.  As such, it should be much larger.  The standard for this type of circuit is at least 10 x R1.  Why 10 x?  Because . . .

An extra advantage of this is that it makes the math much less complex.  If R2 >> R1, then in the denominator, everything to the right of 0.693 reduces to essentially 1.  Hmmm...  The link to the app note is broken, and there is something about that equation that doesn't look right.

As others have said, the chip really needs power supply decoupling close to its power pins.